# Creating Input Box on C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, inputbox

I have a c# windows form in which I need a pop-up box to appear if the an arraylist that is populated contains more than one item so the user can select one of the items from that arraylist.  I would like to avoid creating a seperate windows form for this if possible.  Is it possible to create an input box that would stay on this form and look similar to a messageBox.  The main problem is that I need to halt the code on this form from continuing to run until after the user either selects an item from the so called input box or cancels or closes out of the input box.  Then the code would either resume with the value from the arraylist the user selected in the input box or it would jump out of this sequence of code and do nothing if the user decides to not select an item from the input box.  I have never done anything like this before and would appreciate suggestions for the most efficient way of accomplishing this.  Thanks

Comment: Can you eliminate duplicates before you proceed into entering your loop ( I assume it is a loop being you need it to halt)

Comment: It won't be duplicates they will be unique values in the ArrayList.  I need the user to select which one they want.

Answer (score 1):

When I have done this in the past I just create a small Form with a ListView to fill with the array items. Add your "OK" and "Cancel" Buttons. With your OK click handler, set the Dialog Result to OK:

```
this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
this.Close();
```

Do the same for your Cancel Button:

```
this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
this.Close();
```

From your main code where you want to display the form call `ShowDialog();` This will force the user to complete the interaction with the Dialog box before moving forward. This also returns the DialogResult you set earlier.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was what I was thinking, but I do have one question.  When the small form you are mentioning is displayed when ShowDialog() is called will the code on the initial form hault until the newly displayed form is closed?

Comment: Typically I will have an `if` statement following the `ShowDialog` to see what the user did: `if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)` and this is not evaluated until the Dialog Form is closed. I suppose if you have a timer executing in the background it will still execute while the Dialog is displayed.

Comment: So does the DialogResult on the Dialog Form need to be a public variable so it can be checked on the initial form?

Comment: No. It is returned by ShowDialog. For example: `var result = myForm.ShowDialog();`. Here result is the DialogResult from your Form.